# use a cmake from cvmfs directory for vscode cmake.cmakepath

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I'm doing remote development and when setting up a project I need to use a cmake installed in cvmfs path but vscode don't recognize it (Bad cmake executable) is there a way to make it work

I tried to look for a cvmfs extension for vscode but I don't see any

Comment: so the cvmfs is mounted? can you run `cmake --version` via commandline? do you see any related messages in the Output Panel's CMake channel? Or in the devtools? (run `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` in the command palette)